# Is there any alternate way to select the values in this case statement rather than subqueries

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I know some degree of MySQL, but I'm not sure if there's a more correct way to do what I'm doing here.

```
#Select Ticket ID, Ticket Title, Assigned To
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT
        ti.number, ti.ticket_id, foev.value AS "ticket_name",
        CASE WHEN ti.staff_id = 0 AND ti.team_id = 0
            then
                "** Unassigned **"
            ELSE
                CASE when ti.staff_id = 0
                    THEN
                        (SELECT te.name FROM ost_team te WHERE te.team_id = ti.team_id)
                    ELSE
                        (SELECT CONCAT(st.firstname,LEFT(st.lastname,1)) FROM ost_staff st WHERE st.staff_id = ti.staff_id)
                    END
        END AS "assigned_to"
    FROM ost_ticket ti
        LEFT JOIN ost_form_entry foe ON foe.object_id = ti.ticket_id AND foe.object_type = "T" 
        LEFT JOIN ost_form_entry_values foev ON foev.entry_id = foe.id 
        GROUP BY ti.ticket_id) 
    AS ticket_meta_list 
ORDER BY ticket_id ASC;
```

Is there a more correct way to do those subqueries? I'm thinking there may be with joins that I'm less familiar with.

Comment: you don't need `SELECT * FROM (subquery)`, you can just put `ORDER BY` in the subquery itself.

Comment: That's to support a where clause which isn't included in what I asked.  I eventually will be filtering it by the 'assigned_to' column.

Comment: You can do that with `HAVING assigned_to = ...`

Comment: For this example yes.  I'm preparing some base queries (the sub query) and the outer one will be done by a third part app which filters based on what I send it.  The outer query is simulating their end, not mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your staff table has no *staff_id* with value 0, and your team table has no *team_id* with value 0, you can use `left join` in combination with `coalesce`:

```
SELECT    ti.number,
          ti.ticket_id,
          foev.value AS ticket_name,
          COALESCE(CONCAT(st.firstname,LEFT(st.lastname,1)),
                   te.name, '** Unassigned **') AS assigned_to
FROM      ost_ticket ti
LEFT JOIN ost_form_entry foe 
       ON foe.object_id = ti.ticket_id 
      AND foe.object_type = 'T' 
LEFT JOIN ost_form_entry_values foev 
       ON foev.entry_id = foe.id 
LEFT JOIN ost_team te 
       ON te.team_id = ti.team_id
LEFT JOIN ost_staff st 
       ON st.staff_id = ti.staff_id
GROUP BY  ti.ticket_id 
ORDER BY  ticket_id
```

Comment: Yep, those tables start at 1.  This works perfectly; thank you.  I knew there had to be some cleaner way to do that.